# Accessing eigenvalues in eigen3

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I am trying to set up eigen3 eigenvalue solver and it looks like I faced some complications. The code compiles well, but then fails at some point. The piece of code that fails is

```
EigenSolver<MatrixXd> eigensolver(A);
cout << "tell me something" << endl;
Matrix<complex<double>, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> E = eigensolver.eigenvalues();
cout << "tell me something more" << endl;
cout << E;
```

and the output with an error message:

```
tell me something
tell me something more
(3.5,1.93649)
class_out: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:407: Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::Scalar &Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::operator()(Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::Index) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>]: Assertion `index >= 0 && index < size()' failed.
(3.5,-1.93649)Aborted
```

This looks a bit weird, but it doesn't look like it's an issue of the `<<` operator, as ordinary

```
cout << eigensolver.eigenvalues();
```

works fine as well as `cout` for an ordinary matrix. Also, I've checked eigenvalues of A with Mathematica and I got exactly (3.5,1.93649) and (3.5,-1.93649).

Does anyone know why this is happening, or maybe someone could suggest other way to access eigenvalues?

Comment: Can you include a http://sscce.org/ ?

Comment: Apparently, I've just managed to fix the issue myslef with some help of a friend. I will post the solution in answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution appeared to be quite trivial:

```
EigenSolver<MatrixXd> eigensolver(A);
cout << "tell me something" << endl;
complex<double> E;
cout << "tell me something more" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < A.rows(); ++i){
E = eigensolver.eigenvalues().col(0)[i];
cout << E << endl;
}
```